# No module named 'admin_ordering' even after pip install admin_ordering in venv and it shows in /venv/lib/

Tags: python, django

ok my settings INSTALLED_APPS looks like this

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'correlator.apps.CorrelatorConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'admin_ordering', 
]
```

After installing with pip with venv activated

```
pip intall admin_ordering
```

I see in venv/admin_ordering

in my models.py

```
    import datetime
from flag.models import Flag
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericRelation
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
```

what step am I missing?

Comment: Hi, 1. Can you cross-check that you are installing lib in the correct virtual environment 2. Add the output of `pip freeze` of venv in question

Comment: ok no it is not listed and not in the /venv/lib after pip install.  I am running terminal from the site folder with manage.py in it and venv activated.